SSLHandshakeException on Windows but not Ubuntu
I have a web application which sends an email written in Java using SpringBoot.  The application runs perfectly in Ubuntu (24.0.1), but the following exception is generated in windows:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid 
certification path to requested target

Both platforms are using:
java version "17.0.6" 2023-01-17 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+9-LTS-190)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.6+9-LTS-190, mixed mode, sharing)

Any clues would be appreciated

In my experience with Java, PKIX issues are solved by putting certificates in the right place. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ

Many thanks for your comment, I don't know what certificate I need and where to get it from for this email server.  Can you help me with this please?

Does your app make a call to an external server like gmail or twilio? If so, you may need to get the certificate from that server, or you could do a google search like "windows PKIX java certificate gmail" and see what turns up. Without more detail, that's all I can do for now.

@CaptainChaos Thanks for your reply, no it doesn't use these, but as a said this code works perfectly under ubuntu and I don't recall having to get any certificates.  The mail server is mail.waldenarmy.org.uk.  I was wondering if I copy the cacerts file from ubuntu to windows this would solve the problem?

I would guess you could copy the certs from ubuntu. You could probably also get them from waldenarmy or whoever their mail server uses. Good luck, let me know if it works!
